# How to find a socket's local port number? (Windows C++)

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, binding, port

I'm new to Windows networking, and I am trying to find out which PORT number my socket is bound to (C++, Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010 Professional). It is a UDP socket, and from what I understand, using the following initial setup should bind it to a random available port/address:

```
sockaddr_in local;
local.sin_family = AF_INET;
local.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
local.sin_port = 0; //randomly selected port
int result = bind(clientSock, (sockaddr*)&local, sizeof(local));
//result is always 0
```

As far as using this method, it works for sending data or binding it to a specific port (replacing the 0 with a desired port number). What I need is to bind it randomly, and then find out which port it was bound to afterwards. Is there any way I can do this? It seems that the "local" struct contains "0.0.0.0" as the IP address and "0" as the PORT number.

Thanks for any and all help! I appreciate it.

Comment: re: why not generate a random port -- because that random port might already be in use by some other program or service.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham Why not let the system do exactly that, which is what it already does by default, without the risk of it being in use, and then use the API provided for the purpose of finding out what it was?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`getsockname`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  For example:

```
struct sockaddr_in sin;
int addrlen = sizeof(sin);
if(getsockname(clientSock, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, &addrlen) == 0 &&
   sin.sin_family == AF_INET &&
   addrlen == sizeof(sin))
{
    int local_port = ntohs(sin.sin_port);
}
else
    ; // handle error
```

This also works for *nix-based systems, but note that some systems define the third argument of `getsockname` to be of type `socklen_t*` instead of `int*`, so you might get warnings about pointers differing in signedness if you're writing cross-platform code.

Comment: "int local_port = sin.sin_port;" --> int local_port = ntohs(sin.sin_port);